# JDK 1.8 with error "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

Tags: java

I have a problem with SSLHandshake. I have an application with jdk 1.8 and the vendor who provide the WSDL server with only support jdk 1.7

The vendor has provided us the file `jssecacerts`, with the documentation with main content that `Copy the file into %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security` .

And actually, I tried with his method and it is working file with jdk 1.7. However, I cannot figure it out with jdk 1.8 and the error info below.

I am using `HttpClient 3.1` because of vendor's demo file.

Here is my sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        String sslKeyStorePassword = "changeit";
        String sslKeyStoreType = "JKS"; 
        String sslTrustStore = "/Users/adam/Documents/shanghai-vpn/jssecacerts";
        String sslTrustStorePassword = "changeit";
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", sslKeyStorePath);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",
               sslKeyStorePassword);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", sslKeyStoreType);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", sslTrustStore);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", sslTrustStorePassword);
        MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager =
                new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(connectionManager);

        Protocol myhttps = new Protocol("https", new MySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443);
        Protocol.registerProtocol("https", myhttps);
        loginVPN(httpClient);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static void loginVPN(HttpClient httpClient)
        throws Exception {
    //STEP1:
    HttpClientParams httparams = new HttpClientParams();
    httparams.setSoTimeout(30000);
    httpClient.setParams(httparams);

    httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost("vpn.shanghai-cis.com.cn", 80);

    PostMethod login = new PostMethod(step1URI);
    login.addRequestHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    httpClient.executeMethod(login);

    cookies = httpClient.getState().getCookies();
    System.out.println("==========Cookies============");
    int i = 0;
    for (Cookie c : cookies) {
        System.out.println(++i + ":   " + c);
    }
    httpClient.getState().addCookies(cookies);
    login.releaseConnection();


    //STEP2:
    PostMethod login2 = new PostMethod(step2URI);
    login2.addRequestHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    login2.addRequestHeader("Refer", step1URI);
    login2.addRequestHeader("Accept", "image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*");


    NameValuePair tgroup = new NameValuePair("tgroup", "");
    NameValuePair next = new NameValuePair("next", "");
    NameValuePair tgcookieset = new NameValuePair("tgcookieset", "");
    NameValuePair Login = new NameValuePair("Login", "登录");
    NameValuePair Email = new NameValuePair("username", username);
    NameValuePair password1 = new NameValuePair("password", password);
    // NameValuePair code = new NameValuePair( "code"
    // ,"????");//��ʱ����Ҫ��֤�룬��ʱδ���

    NameValuePair[] data = { tgroup , next , tgcookieset, Login, Email, password1 };
    login2.setRequestBody(data);

    httpClient.executeMethod(login2);

    cookies = httpClient.getState().getCookies();
    System.out.println("==========Cookies============");
    int j = 0;
    for (Cookie c : cookies) {
        System.out.println(++j + ":   " + c);
    }
    httpClient.getState().addCookies(cookies);
    login2.releaseConnection();
}
```

And the error exceptions:

```
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
main, setSoTimeout(30000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1481548099 bytes = { 124, 16, 201, 38, 215, 71, 235, 91, 191, 248, 50, 237, 230, 137, 196, 155, 59, 106, 75, 151, 240, 243, 107, 61, 130, 213, 232, 204 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=vpn.shanghai-cis.com.cn]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 183
0000: 01 00 00 B3 03 01 58 4F   A1 43 7C 10 C9 26 D7 47  ......XO.C...&.G
0010: EB 5B BF F8 32 ED E6 89   C4 9B 3B 6A 4B 97 F0 F3  .[..2.....;jK...
0020: 6B 3D 82 D5 E8 CC 00 00   2C C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0  k=......,.....5.
0030: 05 C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  ....9.8...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 08 C0   12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00  ..3.2...........
0050: 16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00   5E 00 0A 00 34 00 32 00  ........^...4.2.
0060: 17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00   15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00  ................
0070: 0A 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00   19 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00  ................
0080: 10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00   04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00  ................
0090: 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00   00 00 1C 00 1A 00 00 17  ................
00A0: 76 70 6E 2E 73 68 61 6E   67 68 61 69 2D 63 69 73  vpn.shanghai-cis
00B0: 2E 63 6F 6D 2E 63 6E                               .com.cn
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 183
[Raw write]: length = 188
0000: 16 03 01 00 B7 01 00 00   B3 03 01 58 4F A1 43 7C  ...........XO.C.
0010: 10 C9 26 D7 47 EB 5B BF   F8 32 ED E6 89 C4 9B 3B  ..&.G.[..2.....;
0020: 6A 4B 97 F0 F3 6B 3D 82   D5 E8 CC 00 00 2C C0 0A  jK...k=......,..
0030: C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F   00 39 00 38 C0 09 C0 13  ...5.....9.8....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A  ./.....3.2......
0050: C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13   00 FF 01 00 00 5E 00 0A  .............^..
0060: 00 34 00 32 00 17 00 01   00 03 00 13 00 15 00 06  .4.2............
0070: 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00 18   00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00 0D  ................
0080: 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11   00 02 00 12 00 04 00 05  ................
0090: 00 14 00 08 00 16 00 0B   00 02 01 00 00 00 00 1C  ................
00A0: 00 1A 00 00 17 76 70 6E   2E 73 68 61 6E 67 68 61  .....vpn.shangha
00B0: 69 2D 63 69 73 2E 63 6F   6D 2E 63 6E              i-cis.com.cn
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1565)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.umoney.finance.Login.loginVPN(Login.java:69)
    at com.umoney.finance.Login.main(Login.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0):

TLS/SSL is well specified protocol, so there should be no dependency on the JDK version. The *jssecacerts* file only should replace the list of trusted certificates (the question is - do you want to do that? I'd just import the certificates in the jssecacerts into a truststore).

Now - see the SSL debug:

- your client sent the SSL client request
- SSL server sent an alert response
- you client received the alert response (handshake_failure) and threw an exception

it means the server refused parameters provided by your client.

First question - does the SSL server require a client X.509 authentication? (mutual SSL). Then the client needs to have a private key and certificate trusted by the server.

Your client supports only limited subset of the protocols (which is ok from the security perspective until the protocols are safe). Check if the server supports at least one if them.

Comment: Dear @Gabriel Vince, 

In the debug log, there are there lines like:
`*** ClientHello, TLSv1`
`main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2`
`main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure`

Does the TLS version related?  I forced my client with `-Djavax.net.debug=all -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1" -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1"  -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false  -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=true`

Many thanks

Comment: Indeed. You should check what protocols are supported by the server (should be visible in the ssl debug log). It is very probable the TLSv1 may not be supported as it has some weaknesses. What happens if you disable the switches and let the client and server find the best match?

Comment: Just thinking - immediate alert with failure - the server doesn't allow TLSv1 or neither of the supported TLS protocols or requires a client certificate.

Comment: This is the vendor provided that how to generate the [jssecacerts](http://umoney-10063217.cos.myqcloud.com/InstallCert.java), in this file looks like it used TLS, would you help take a look?